# How to prevent multiple clicks on slider arrows until slider animation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider with arrows. When I click on these arrows a lot of times, the slider continually slides depending on how many times I click the arrow. How do you prevent clicking on the arrow until the sliding animation is done?

Please see what I mean in my pen here: http://codepen.io/gianaguilar/pen/JGaxKL

Try clicking on the arrows multiple times and how the slider responds. I need to be able to slide one click at a time.

Thank you!

Here is the jquery code

```
var $visibleSlide, getDataSlide, sliderInterval, getDataNextSlide, getDataPrevSlide, getDataNavDot;
var fadeDuration = 1000;
var pause = 8000;

//show first slide
$('.slides li:first-child').css('display', 'block');

//show first nav dot
$('.nav li:first-child').addClass('active-cd');

//find out what slide is visible and get its data attribute
function getSlideInfo() {
  $visibleSlide = $('.slides').find('li:visible');
  getDataSlide = $visibleSlide.data('n');
  getDataNextSlide = $visibleSlide.next().data('n');
  getDataPrevSlide = $visibleSlide.prev().data('n');
}

//show next slide
function showNextSlide() {
  getSlideInfo();

  $('.nav li').removeClass('active-cd');

  if (getDataSlide < 3) {
    $visibleSlide.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
    $visibleSlide.next().fadeIn(fadeDuration);
    $('.nav li[data-cd=' + getDataNextSlide + ']').addClass('active-cd');
  } else {
    $visibleSlide.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
    $('.slides li:first-child').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
    $('.nav li:first-child').addClass('active-cd');
  }
} //end showNextSlide

function showPrevSlide() {
  getSlideInfo();

  $('.nav li').removeClass('active-cd');

  if (getDataSlide > 1) {
    $visibleSlide.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
    $visibleSlide.prev().fadeIn(fadeDuration);
    $('.nav li[data-cd=' + getDataPrevSlide + ']').addClass('active-cd');
  } else {
    $visibleSlide.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
    $('.slides li:last-child').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
    $('.nav li:last-child').addClass('active-cd');
  }

} // end showPrevSlide

// controls
$('.next').on('click', showNextSlide);
$('.prev').on('click', showPrevSlide);

//autoplay
function startSlider() {
  sliderInterval = setInterval(showNextSlide, pause)
}
startSlider();
$('.slideshow').mouseenter(function() {
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
});
$('.slideshow').mouseleave(startSlider);

//control dots clicks
$('.nav li').on('click', function() {
  getDataNavDot = $(this).data('cd');
  getSlideInfo();

  $('.nav li').removeClass('active-cd');
  $(this).addClass('active-cd');

  $visibleSlide.fadeOut(fadeDuration);
  $('.slides li[data-n=' + getDataNavDot + ']').fadeIn(fadeDuration);
}); //end dots click
```

Comment: look into .is(':animated') - https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/ - and .stop() - https://api.jquery.com/stop/ - basically tell your prev and next to return if the slides are busy

Comment: One way would be to disable the click event for a specific amount of time to give your animation time to finish before the user would be allowed to click again. [See this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002366/javascript-disable-the-click-event-for-1-second-after-an-id-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a variable `isAnimating` that is set to `true` when you are in the next or previous slide function, and set to `false` when the animation is complete (within a callback function to one of your fade functions).

A simple check at the top of these next and previous functions to return false if the `isAnimating` function is set to true will prevent the animations from queuing up.

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXPOQY